# how to create service principle key in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I need to create a service connection in Azure DevOps for service type "Azure Resource Manager".
When I am trying "Service principal (automatic)", I am able to do with proper permission. But when I am trying "Service principal (manual)", it needs service principle key. May I know how to create it from Azure Portal?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret

Comment: Just for the confirmation, I am asking. Is Service Principle key and Value under Client Secrets are same?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Comment: When I use that secret in service connection, I am getting the error as "Failed to query service connection API: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXX?api-version=2016-06-01'. Status Code: 'Forbidden', Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'XXXXXXXXX' with object id 'XXXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXXX' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}'". Any other steps am I missing?

Comment: Have you assigned a role to the app registration/service principal in the Azure subscription?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as mentioned by @juunas, the `service principle key` is also named `client secret`, you can create it in your App Registration -> `Certificates & secrets` in the portal, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

For the `Forbidden` error, it means your service principal does not have the correct RBAC role in your subscription, just navigate to your subscription in the portal -> add an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor` for your service principal like below, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

[image]